Not able to parse gzip response type(content-encoding:gzip) in Lua envoy filter
I am trying to send response to an express endpoint. It works when response doesn't have any header  as content-encoding:gzip.
It doesn't work when this header is present. Is there any way I can decompress the response and iterate using bodychunks and send it to express endpoint
Below is my Lua filter
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
kind: EnvoyFilter
metadata:
  name: cle-lua-filter-traceception
  namespace: content-layout-enricher
spec:
  workloadSelector:
    labels:
      app: content-layout-enricher-teflon
  configPatches:
    - applyTo: HTTP_FILTER
      match:
        context: SIDECAR_OUTBOUND
        listener:
          filterChain:
            filter:
              name: envoy.filters.network.http_connection_manager
              subFilter:
                name: envoy.filters.http.router
      patch:
        operation: INSERT_BEFORE
        value:
          name: envoy.lua
          typed_config:
            '@type': type.googleapis.com/envoy.extensions.filters.http.lua.v3.Lua
            inlineCode: |
              function envoy_on_request(request_handle)
                local headers = request_handle:headers()
                local optimusHeader = headers:get("x-o-optimus")
                
                if optimusHeader == "x-o-tracelogs" then
                  local traceparent = headers:get("traceparent")
                  local wmsvc = headers:get("wm_svc.name")
                  local requestBody = ""
                  for chunk in request_handle:bodyChunks() do
                    if (chunk:length() > 0) then
                      requestBody = requestBody .. chunk:getBytes(0, chunk:length())
                    end
                  end
                  local finalBodyString = requestBody .. "|~|" .. traceparent .. "|~|" .. "content-layout-enricher" .. "|~|" .. "request" .. "|~|" .. 200  .. "|~|" ..  wmsvc
                  request_handle:streamInfo():dynamicMetadata():set("envoy.filters.http.lua", "x-condition", "tracelogs")
                  request_handle:streamInfo():dynamicMetadata():set("envoy.filters.http.lua", "traceception", traceparent)
                  request_handle:streamInfo():dynamicMetadata():set("envoy.filters.http.lua", "x-svcName", "content-layout-enricher")
                  request_handle:streamInfo():dynamicMetadata():set("envoy.filters.http.lua", "upstream-service-name", wmsvc)

                  local headers, body, err = request_handle:httpCall(
                  "traceception_cluster",
                  {
                    [":method"] = "POST",
                    [":path"] = "/logs",
                    [":authority"] = "<external express endpoint>",
                    ["content-type"] = "text/plain",
                    ["content-length"] = string.len(finalBodyString)
                  },
                  finalBodyString,
                  10000,
                  true)
                end
              end
              function envoy_on_response(response_handle)
                local dynamic_metadata = response_handle:streamInfo():dynamicMetadata():get("envoy.filters.http.lua")
                local condition_value = dynamic_metadata and dynamic_metadata["x-condition"]
                local traceparent = dynamic_metadata and dynamic_metadata["traceception"]
                local svcName = dynamic_metadata and dynamic_metadata["x-svcName"]
                local response_status_code = response_handle:headers():get(":status")
                local upstream_service_name = dynamic_metadata and dynamic_metadata["upstream-service-name"]
                local envoyUpstreamResTime = response_handle:headers():get("x-envoy-upstream-service-time")

                if condition_value == "tracelogs" then
                  local responseBody = ""
                    for chunk in response_handle:bodyChunks() do
                      if (chunk:length() > 0) then
                        responseBody = responseBody .. chunk:getBytes(0, chunk:length())
                      end
                    end
                  local finalBodyString = responseBody .. "|~|" .. traceparent .. "|~|" .. svcName .. "|~|" .. "response" .. "|~|" .. response_status_code .. "|~|" .. upstream_service_name .. "|~|"  .. envoyUpstreamResTime 
                  local headers, body, err = response_handle:httpCall(
                  "traceception_cluster",
                  {
                    [":method"] = "POST",
                    [":path"] = "/logs",
                    [":authority"] = "<express endpoint>",
                    ["content-type"] = "text/plain",
                    ["content-length"] = string.len(finalBodyString)
                  },
                  finalBodyString,
                  10000,
                  true)
                end
              end
    - applyTo: CLUSTER
      match:
        context: ANY
      patch:
        operation: ADD
        value:
          name: traceception_cluster
          type: STRICT_DNS
          connect_timeout: 5s
          lb_policy: ROUND_ROBIN
          load_assignment:
            cluster_name: traceception_cluster
            endpoints:
              - lb_endpoints:
                  - endpoint:
                      address:
                        socket_address:
                          address: >-
                            express_endpoint
                          port_value: 80


enter image description here
Getting ascii formatted response when iterating through bodyChunks
